# Web Service as Open Data in CKAN

Tags: ckan, opendata

Is it possible to provide a web service as open data in [CKAN](http://ckan.org/) rather than a dataset? If so how can I get it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *dataset* in CKAN is only a logical container of data. Each dataset can have one or more *resources*. A resource represents primary data, e.g.

- An uploaded file
- A link to a file that was uploaded somewhere else
- A link to an API

[image]

So you can absolutely add the link to an API as a resource to a dataset.

How this data is previewed is again something different. There are several CKAN extensions around that help you to preview data. In the core there is a build in preview for tabular data (CSV, XLS or the like). But if you want to [preview a WMS](http://docs.ckan.org/projects/ckanext-spatial/en/latest/previews.html#wms-preview), you can use the preview provided by [ckanext-spatial](https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-spatial).

So it really depends on the data that you want to preview, but for many common formats there already is a solution. And if not, it would be a great opportunity to create an extension and provide it to the community.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. +1, Could you please tell me the steps to link to an API as you have mentioned.

Comment: In the "Adding a new dataset" section of the [user guide](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/user-guide.html#adding-a-new-dataset) you see how to add a resource to a dataset. There are 3 tabs, one for "Link to a file", "Link to an API" and "Upload a file". Click on "Link to an API" and enter the information of the API you want to add.